# How do I make a .bat menu that uses numbers & letters in the same multi-choice menu?

Tags: batch-file, menu

I'm making a small(ish) utility batch file.
I have a mostly working multi-choice menu, that uses single key strokes (no enter).
I want to use numbers for the first set of choices & then have h & q for help & quit options, respectively. However when I run the .bat in testing & select any option, two lines of text come up, one says "h was unexpected at this time" & a second saying the same thing about q.

The options seem to work correctly, but those messages are annoying, why are they even appearing at all & how do I make them go away?

Here's my code.

```
echo off
cls
:menu1
set mypath=%~dp0
@echo %mypath%
echo.
echo .............
echo intro
echo .............
echo.
echo -more menu text here
echo.   
echo 1 - option
echo 2 - option
echo 3 - option
echo 4 - option
echo 5 - option
echo 6 - option
echo 7 - option
echo h - Help
echo q - Quit Program
echo.
choice /c:1234567hq
if errorlevel 1 set m=1
if errorlevel 2 set m=2
if errorlevel 3 set m=3
if errorlevel 4 set m=4
if errorlevel 5 set m=5
if errorlevel 6 set m=6
if errorlevel 7 set m=7
if errorlevel h set m=h
if errorlevel q set m=q
if %m%==1 goto test
if %m%==2 goto test
if %m%==3 goto test
if %m%==4 goto test
if %m%==5 goto test
if %m%==6 goto test
if %m%==7 goto test
if %m%==h goto test
if %m%==q goto test
:test
echo.
echo Aha! A test message!
echo.
pause
goto menu1
```

One of the reasons I want to use h & q is because I plan on having a second menu, which will also have those options in it & I want them to use the same keys in that menu too. I am trying to make this as straightforward & "user friendly" as possible, so I don't want to have arbitrary letters for all the choices either, if that makes sense.

They don't appear in a regular menu (with enter), but I'd like to have this main menu run commands on single keystrokes if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about `zxscvbnm`/`asdfghjkl` or `qwertyuiop`? These keys are easily accessible, and not arbitray. In my batchc script, I usaully use `zxc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errorlevel` refers to the index of the item in the choice list, and it is always a number. In your example, `h` is 8 and `q` is 9.

Additionally, `if errorlevel [number]` means "if the errorlevel is [number] *or greater*," so either the options need to be listed backwards or you need to use the `%errorlevel%` system variable. The easiest thing to do would be to simply set `m` to `%errorlevel%` and get rid of all of the `goto`s since there's no code between them and the label they're referring to anyway.

```
@echo off
cls
:menu1
set mypath=%~dp0
@echo %mypath%
echo.
echo .............
echo intro
echo .............
echo.
echo -more menu text here
echo.   
echo 1 - option
echo 2 - option
echo 3 - option
echo 4 - option
echo 5 - option
echo 6 - option
echo 7 - option
echo h - Help
echo q - Quit Program
echo.
choice /c:1234567hq
set m=%errorlevel%

:test
echo.
echo Aha! A test message!
echo.
pause
goto menu1
```

Comment: Actually I should add that this is my test script & the finished one will have multiple subroutines, this just has the one :test one attached to all the options, but I plan to have the options goto different subroutines. So I realized the set m=%errorlevel% won't work for that. I will try the backward listing however.

Comment: Note: You can even create labels in your code like this `:label1` and `:label2` somewhere else and then just use `goto label%m%` and get rid of a load of if statements :)

Comment: @ShojoDagger: you could for example use just one `goto :label-%errorlevel%` instead of 9 different `goto`s.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: `:D`

Comment: @Stephan Wow `:D` That does not happen all day ^^

Comment: Okay. I realized that since the m variable is being set to the error level & the goto reads the m variable...I just replace the individual errorlevels with the %errorlevel% string. Then I just have the goto lines numbered. As long as I keep the choices & gotos in relative order it should work with as many options as I want, tied to whatever keys I want on the user side. @geisterfurz007 & Stephan. Good ideas, but since I'm going to have a sub menu, I don't think it'll work in this case, since it would make menu2's options the same as the 1st menu? I'll experiment with it though.

Comment: So what about using a different label base name then? e. g., `:menu_A_` and `:menu_B_`, then you can distinguish between the two menus when appending the numbers?

Comment: @aschipfl I did think of that. The reason that I thought it might not work was that I thought I  would have some crossreferenced subroutines used by both menus. However as I got it typed out & tested I found that I didn't need to crossreference, so using two sets of labels works great & the only subroutine I have to "duplicate" is the exit command.  Thanks for all the helpful advice, y'all.